# Gradle buildConfigField: Syntax for arrays & maps?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The android gradle documentation says about buildConfigField:

> ```
> void buildConfigField(String type, String name, String value)
> ```
>
> Adds a new field to the generated BuildConfig class. The field is generated as: type name = value;
>
> This means each of these must have valid Java content. If the type is a String, then the value should include quotes.

I can't find any information about the syntax of buildConfigField values for Arrays, Arraylist or a HashMap? Since they are compiled into java code usually everything should be possible.

Does anyone has some examples or documentation?

Comment: It's Groovy code. So if you want to know syntax, look there.

Comment: This is not about groovy syntax, more or less about available types. But I solved the question in the meanwhile...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For array

app.gradle

```
        buildConfigField "String[]", "URL_ARRAY",
        "{" +
        "\"http:someurl\"," +
        "\"http:someurl\"," +
        "\"http:someurl\"" +
        "}"
```

For Map

```
        buildConfigField "java.util.Map<String, String>", "NAME_MAP", 
                 "new java.util.HashMap<String, " +
                 "String>() {{ put(\"name\", \"John\"); put(\"name1\",  \"John\"); put(\"name2\", " +
                "\"John\"); }}"
```

Access in code:

```
HashMap<String, String> name = (HashMap<String, String>) BuildConfig.NAME_MAP;
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the reason for using `buildConfig` fields is to keep important data out of the code - like environment variables.

another example - static arrays + gradle.properties (requires Gradle 2.13 or above):

gradle.properties:

```
nonNullStringArray=new String[]{ \n\
    \"foo\",\n\
    \"bar\"\n}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildConfigField "String[]", "nonNullStringArray", (project.findProperty("nonNullStringArray") ?: "new String[]{}")

buildConfigField "String[]", "nullableStringArray", (project.findProperty("nullableStringArray") ?: "null")
```

Answer (score 3):

Another example here

**Gradle file with environments :**

```
ext {
    // Environments list
    apiUrl = [
            prod         : "https://website.com",
            preprod      : "https://preprod.website.com"
    ]
}
```

**Gradle Android file :**

```
private static String getApiUrlHashMapAsString(apiUrlMap) {
    def hashMap = "new java.util.HashMap<String, String>()" + "{" + "{ "
    apiUrlMap.each { k, v -> hashMap += "put(\"${k}\"," + "\"${v}\"" + ");" }
    return hashMap + "}" + "}"
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
         buildConfigField "java.util.Map<String, String>", "API_URLS", getApiUrlHashMapAsString(apiUrl)
    }
}
```

**In your code :**

```
BuildConfig.API_URLS
```

Answer (score 3):

Convenience method for arrays (without escaping):

```
def arrayAsString(String ... args) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("{");
    if(args.length > 0) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            builder.append('"')
            builder.append(arg);
            builder.append('"')
            builder.append(", ")
        }
        builder.setLength(builder.length() - 2)
    }
    builder.append("}");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it now. The parameters are translated 1:1 in java, this means in fact you need to code java inside gradle and escape properly.

For HashSet:

```
buildConfigField "java.util.Set<String>", "MY_SET", "new java.util.HashSet<String>() {{ add(\"a\"); }};"
```