# buildConfigField for collection by reading .properties file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[Gradle buildConfigField: Syntax for arrays & maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130730/gradle-buildconfigfield-syntax-for-arrays-maps) post gives hint to generate `Dictionary`, `Set<T>`, `Collection` or `HashTable<T>` for `buildConfigField`.

I'd like to know it is possible to load `.properties` file and generates a collection variable as `BuildConfig` variables.

**dev.properties**

```
Variable1 = 'some'
Variable2 = 'value'
```

**app.gradle**

```
ext {
    // Read properties file
    Properties devProperty = new Properties()
    def devPropertyFile = file(getRootDir().getPath() + File.separator + 'dev.properties')
    try {
        devProperty.load(new FileInputStream(devPropertyFile))
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        devProperty = null
        System.out.println('devProperty is null')
    }

    // Read property field names as a String set
    Set<String> devSet = devProperty?.stringPropertyNames()
}


android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        // Below trial gives error
        buildConfigField 'java.util.Set<String>', 'PropertyNames', project.devSet
    }
}
```

**Expected result 1**

By accessing `BuildConfig.devSet` in java code has `["Variable1, Variable2"]` values.

**Expected result 2**

It would be good to access `Properties devProperty` itself in application code as below;

`String var1 = BuildConfig.devProperty["Variable1"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created gradle function in order to generate [texted-inline-function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131111/361100).

The example.properties assumes the data types are in `<String, Boolean>` pair.

**example.properties**

```
example1 = true
example2 = false
```

**gradle function**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // read file from project root folder
        buildConfigField 'java.util.Hashtable<String, Boolean>', 'PropertyPairs', makePropertyHashTable(getRootDir().getPath() + File.separator + 'example.properties')
    }
}

def makePropertyHashTable(filename) {
    def devProperties = new Properties()
    try {
        devProperties.load(new FileInputStream(file(filename)))
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        devProperties = null
        System.out.println('devProperties value is null')
    }

    // result example: new Hashtable<String, Boolean>(){{ put(true, "a"); }};
    def prefix = 'new java.util.Hashtable<String, Boolean>(){{ '
    def suffix = '}}'
    def value = ''
    if (devProperties != null) {
        for (d in devProperties) {
                value += String.format('put("%s",%s); ', d.key, d.value)
            }
        }
    }
    return String.format('%s%s%s', prefix, value, suffix)
}
```

**In application code usage**

```
if (BuildConfig.PropertyPairs.getOrDefault("example1", false) == true) {
    // do something
}
```